# some of css stylesheet is not loading

Tags: html, css

My CSS stylesheet loads almost all the contents but it is not loading my CSS for `button`. It's strange because all other things are working fine. I use `opera`. I have posted the CSS below which is not loading, also how I load the CSS.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

```css
    .button {
        background-color: #22a4a3b5;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 4px 14px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin: 0px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hpsj2e0L/

It works fine in the fiddle but not in my site.

Comment: It wouldn't load some of the file and not other parts randomly. I'd suggest sharing the entire style.css using a file sharing service, also provide the HTML that's using it. (ex. jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please show your  HTML code

Comment: Write href="style.css"

Comment: @AAShakil its in the root so /style.css

Comment: @john you've provided a css `.button` is that enclosed with `<style>` tag?

Comment: here is my jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/hpsj2e0L/

Comment: it is wokring in the jsfiddle but not from my site

Comment: @AAShakil  its in another css file , they are not in `<style>` tag but all other css loads fine

Comment: @john If you are using opera mini than go to your url(ex http://localhost.com) and on the url bar type `server:source` and press hit. Then you'll see the page source. Find there <link href......> and notice what's on `href` tag?

Comment: The CSS that is working, is it in the same CSS file? If so  it is possible that there is a syntax error before your `.button` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you put your css in `style` tag or in css file

```
<style>
.button, button {
    background-color: #22a4a3b5;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

also check if you have `.button` class in your html or maybe its `button` tag

Comment: OP states `i have posted the css below which is not loading also how i load the css` I read that has this code is inside the style.css and this is the specific class that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are writing `CSS` inside your `HTML` file without wrapping it into a `<style>` tag. Like this:

```
    <style>
        .button, button {
            background-color: #22a4a3b5;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 4px 14px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 17px;
            margin: 0px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
```

also, you don't need both selectors if you are applying the style to a `<button>` you can just use `button`. 
`.button` is only necessary if you are going to apply it as a class like in `<div class="button"></div>`

Comment: the css is in another file not inside html , what mean both selector ? btw above is my fiddle it loads in the fiddle but not in my site

Comment: @john What i mean by both selectors is that you are setting the style for both button elements an also elements with the class button.  If the code is working in JSfiddle but not in your site is probably because you have some other style being applied to button or .button that is overwriting your styles, try giving it a unique name like `.button-john` to your class and then add that class in your html `class="button-john"` and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Check other style files to `button` class. Try give the different `class` name or load your `style` file later than others.